# How can I make TextMate aware of outside changes?

Tags: mac, text-editors, textmate

When I edit a document with TextMate, and I edit the same document with other tools, it seems that TextMate isn't aware of changes made by the other tools.

I tested with emacs and emEditor, and it looks like the other editors know when the documents they're editing are changed.

Is there any way to make TextMate update its contents as soon as a change happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextMate detects changes on disk upon switching applications back to it.  The easiest way to trigger this is to simply hit command-tab twice. If there were no unsaved changes in TextMate's buffer, then it silently updates the document to the version on disk. If, however, there were unsaved changes, then TextMate will prompt with a warning, allowing you to either keep TextMate's version or to revert to the version on disk.